# Debug an obfuscated .Net assembly

Tags: .net, debugging, runtime, obfuscation, disassembly

I'm trying to asses that the obfuscation I applied to my assembly is enough, my main concern is around protecting strings containing passwords or private keys.
I successfully decompiled my assembly with [Salamander Decompiler](http://www.remotesoft.com/) an saw what my string has been encrypted, but during runtime the string has to be decrypted to be used.
I was told that it is possible to debug the application and see the assembler code, any idea how to do that?

**Solution** 
This worked for me, although there is probably a better way of doing it with WinDbg.

1- Execute the program
2- Open a command line and type:

```
adplus -crash -pn [executablename] -o [ output directory ]
```

* adplus is placed in the same folder as WinDBG

3- Close the program or wait it closes
4- Open the FULLDUMP*.dmp placed in the specified output directory
5- Open NotePad++ anb select TextFX->Characters->Zap all non printable characters to #
6- Search for the string in this format 's#t#r#i#n#g'
or replace all '#' by '' and search 'string' (this may take a while)

*By the way I couldn't find a [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) that was also in the memory in clear text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sensitive data like passwords and private keys you should be using [`SecureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx).

As for seeing the assembler code - when the application is running, you can use [windbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) to get a memory dump and then look at the actual assembler in windbg.

Comment: I can't believe I've never heard of SecureString before!  Most useful.

Comment: SecureString is quite interesting, I'm sure it complicates things to decompilation but surely not the definitive solution because if you have to use the string you need to move it to an unsecured location eventually. I will take a look to the windbg dump.

Comment: @Cristian - how secure do you need this? The fact is, however obfuscated your code, if it runs on a processor, a determined enough hacker will be able to deobfuscate/decompile it.

Comment: I know no data will ever be 100% secure if it is written in the binary. I'm just trying to evaluate how difficult it is to extract it.

Comment: The dump worked well, I can see the strings in plain text. Of course I knew were to set the breakpoint and the string I was searching for was 'password'.

Comment: I'd guess that in this scenario it's be even easier for a hacker. Since he just needs to look after SecureStrings instead of all strings, which reduces the noise by a lot.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to debug some hard-obfuscated application you may consider looking for dnSpy by 0xd4d, its a free and open-source .NET decompiler which is able to let you debug any .NET assembly, & you can put breakpoints and get the var's value. Really interesting as far as debugging is concerned, and let me tell you that being able to debug an app without WinDBG or Olly2 is clearly a pleasure.

Now, about string obfuscation, you can have a look at [.NETGuard's string encryption](http://netguard.io/), which use very complex method (.NET stackframe + private key + resource decryption + pointer) to protect & secure your strings. To my mind protecting strings is a top-priority since hackers go through your app and refer to strings mostly.